# removing trailing 0 (and .) in date time format

Tags: c#, datetime

I got that little code sample to explain what i need to do

[link to donetfiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/Jf58tw)

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff";
            var trimTime = new char[] { '0', '.' };

            var a = new DateTime(2016, 3, 3, 12, 11, 10, 123);
            var b = new DateTime(2016, 3, 3, 12, 11, 10, 120);
            var c = new DateTime(2016, 3, 3, 12, 11, 10, 100);
            var d = new DateTime(2016, 3, 3, 12, 11, 10, 000);

            Console.WriteLine("a {0} expected 2016-03-03T12:11:10.123", a.ToString(format).TrimEnd(trimTime));
            Console.WriteLine("b {0} expected 2016-03-03T12:11:10.12", b.ToString(format).TrimEnd(trimTime));
            Console.WriteLine("c {0} expected 2016-03-03T12:11:10.1", c.ToString(format).TrimEnd(trimTime));
            Console.WriteLine("d {0} expected 2016-03-03T12:11:10", d.ToString(format).TrimEnd(trimTime));

        }
    }
}
```

output

> a 2016-03-03T12:11:10.123 expected 2016-03-03T12:11:10.123
>   b 2016-03-03T12:11:10.12 expected 2016-03-03T12:11:10.12
>   c 2016-03-03T12:11:10.1 expected 2016-03-03T12:11:10.1
>   d 2016-03-03T12:11:1 expected 2016-03-03T12:11:10

you can see that my method remove too much in the last case.

what would be the solution to removed the trailing `0` and `.` without touching the seconds part ?

Comment: a regex would be handy or you could look at the milliseconds property and conditionally change the format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your format string to capital `F`s:

```
string format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFF";
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_13):

> ## The "FFF" Custom Format Specifier
>
> The "FFF" custom format specifier represents the three most significant digits of the seconds fraction; that is, it represents the milliseconds in a date and time value. However, **trailing zeros or three zero digits are not displayed**.

Output (removing the `TrimEnd` from each line:

```
a 2016-03-03T12:11:10.123 expected 2016-03-03T12:11:10.123
b 2016-03-03T12:11:10.12  expected 2016-03-03T12:11:10.12
c 2016-03-03T12:11:10.1   expected 2016-03-03T12:11:10.1
d 2016-03-03T12:11:10     expected 2016-03-03T12:11:10
```

Comment: Definitely the best way to achieve what the OP wanted

Comment: exactly what i wanted, going to wait the 5 minutes needed before i can accept this answer